# Should I encrypt the response that triggers an Ajax action? Is nonce sufficient?

Tags: users, login, security, user-meta, user-registration

I am trying to write a custom user registration plugin. The plugin has 5 basic functionalities

1. Take form data and create a user using `wp_insert_iser`
2. Once a user is created, update user meta for additional fields
3. Send Email
4. Send SMS
5. Send to Whatsapp

To make the whole process faster I have created 5 ajax actions for the above 5 steps. Once the first step is completed I send success nonce for every action something like :

```php
if ($user_id) // Successfully user is created

$data = [
'user_id' => $user_id,
'next_actions' = [
    'update_meta_field' => wp_create_nonce($userid . 'update_meta_field')),
    'send_sms' => wp_create_nonce($userid . 'send_sms')),
    'send_mail' => wp_create_nonce($userid . 'send_email'),
    'send_whatsapp' => wp_create_nonce($userid . 'send_whatsapp')
]];

wp_send_json_success($data);
```

Once the response has been received at the client side, 4 ajax actions are triggered on `ajaxSuccess` event and executed asynchronously. E.g

```js
$document.ajaxSuccess(function( event, request, settings, response ) {

        let next_actions = response.data.next_actions;
        let user_id = response.data.user_id;

        $.each(next_actions, function (action, nonce) {
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:{
                    action: action,
                    nonce : nonce,
                    user_id: user_id,
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

On server side I do something like :-

```php
if( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], $_POST['user_id'] . $_POST['action'] ) ){
  // Send mail or Update user fields or anything else
}
```

**So my queries are**

1. Are there any security flaws in my approach?
2. Is nonce sufficient for it or should I encrypt the response because I am exposing user_id or username to clients? Does WordPress provide any native encryption/decryption function or methods?
3. I required to share some variables between 5 actions. I choose `set_transient` to share form data across all the actions. Is it efficient? Or should I go for `SESSION`? I heard some hosting servers strip the session id from the header. Is it? Any alternative performance efficient way, please?